# Execute a function everytime a condition is true without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I execute a function every time that I call it without reloading the page and get different values from it based on id?

Html code:

```
<a href="#" id="next"> click here </a>
```

And jQuery code:

```
$("#next").click(function() {
    var div1vis = $(".left-div .info-left-div").filter(':visible'), 
        div2vis = $(".right-div .info-right-div").filter(':visible');
    var id = jQuery(this).attr("id");

    if (div1vis.next().length > 0 && div2vis.next().length > 0) {
        var nextid = div1vis.next().attr("id");
        changebackground(nextid);
        div1vis.next().show().prev().hide();
        div2vis.next().show().prev().hide();
    }
});

function changebackground(divid) {   
    if (divid = '#left-info1') { $("body").css('background-color', '#ebb614'); } 
    if (divid = '#left-info2') { $("body").css('background-color', '#acb7a8'); } 
    if (divid = '#left-info3') { $("body").css('background-color', '#4f795b'); } 
    if (divid = '#left-info4') { $("body").css('background-color', '#7f7a6e'); } 
    if (divid = '#left-info5') { $("body").css('background-color', '#4a87a2'); } 
    if (divid = '#left-info6') { $("body").css('background-color', '#121929');} 
    if (divid = '#left-info7') { $("body").css('background-color', '#1b5367'); } 
    if (divid = '#left-info8') { $("body").css('background-color', '#13192e'); }
}
```

Comment: I dont really understand , what is the problem ?

Comment: put some more code and explanation; my preliminary analysis says `divid = '#left-info4'` is always true so; you may be trying to do like `divid == 'left-info4'`

Comment: see your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1yscy5ts/15/ and my answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be what you want !

```js
$("#next").click(function() {
  var div1vis = $(".left-div .info-left-div").filter(':visible'),
      div2vis = $(".right-div .info-right-div").filter(':visible');

  var id = jQuery(this).attr("id");

  if (   div1vis.next('.left-div .info-left-div').length > 0 
      && div2vis.next('.right-div .info-right-div').length > 0 ) {

    var nextid = div1vis.next('.left-div .info-left-div').attr("id");

    changebackground(nextid);

    div1vis.next().show().prev().hide();
    div2vis.next().show().prev().hide();
  }
});


function changebackground(divid) {

  var colors = {
    'left-info1': '#ebb614',
    'left-info2': '#acb7a8',
    'left-info3': '#4f795b',
    'left-info4': '#7f7a6e',
    'left-info5': '#4a87a2',
    'left-info6': '#121929',
    'left-info7': '#1b5367',
    'left-info8': '#13192e',

  };
  var curColor = colors[divid];
  if (curColor) {
    //$('#' + divid).show();
    $("body").css('background-color', curColor);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have assignments happening in your function instead of comparisons so you will never get the results you are expecting. Try this:

```
function changebackground(divid) {   
    if (divid == '#left-info1') { $("body").css('background-color', '#ebb614'); } 
    if (divid == '#left-info2') { $("body").css('background-color', '#acb7a8'); } 
    if (divid == '#left-info3') { $("body").css('background-color', '#4f795b'); } 
    if (divid == '#left-info4') { $("body").css('background-color', '#7f7a6e'); } 
    if (divid == '#left-info5') { $("body").css('background-color', '#4a87a2'); } 
    if (divid == '#left-info6') { $("body").css('background-color', '#121929');} 
    if (divid == '#left-info7') { $("body").css('background-color', '#1b5367'); } 
    if (divid == '#left-info8') { $("body").css('background-color', '#13192e'); }
}
```